# Is there a way to smoothly play video directly from a Blu-ray drive?

Tags: raspbian, video

I tried to play compressed `.mkv` and compressed `.m2ts` and it works perfectly with omxplayer. I am just curious to know if I overclock my Pi to run `.m2ts` straight from a Blu-ray so it will not be laggy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean straight from a Bluray?

Comment: I think he means by not playing it off his SD card as ripped content but  instead from his BlurayROM (most likely connected via USB)It seems reading of BlurayROM is choppy but playing from file not.. interesting..

Comment: Hi MrPackizz - welcome to Stack Exchange. What have you tried? Did you copy the .m2ts from a disk on another machine onto an SD Card?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without further information.

Comment: I suppose there is a CSS-like encryption on Bluerays (as there were for DVDs). Maybe [MrPackizz](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/1048/mrpackizz) is referring to the difference in smoothness with and without encryption?

Comment: Over clocking your pie won't change the situation. This is probably a result of the throughput not being enough, and I would start looking at what else is going on over USB.

Answer (score -4):

I do not believe this is possible without the vid licences.  Correct me if I am wrong, sorry.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray_Disc), the encodings used by a Blu-Ray Disc are H.262/MPEG-2 Part 2, H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, and VC-1. The RPi [needs a licence](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1924/797) to decode MPEG-2 and VC-1 only. MPEG-4 is already supported.

Comment: This should be a comment on the original question, and not an answer

Comment: Try air playing it somehow to the pi.  Maybe get a sling box online.

Comment: Http://slingbox.com